# Where to store data loaded from HTTP client in Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a service that loads data from server:

```
@Injectable()
export class AddressingService {
    public addressing: any[] = [];
    public objectlInfo: any;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    loadAddressing(unom: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get();
    }

    getObjectInfo(unom: number, version: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get();
    }
   
    setAddressing(data) {
         this.addressing = data;
    }
   
    getAddressing() {
        return this.addressing;
    }
}
```

How to use service better:

```
this.AddressingService.loadAddressing().subscribe((data) => {
    this.AddressingService.setAddressing(data);
});
```

Or this way:

```
loadAddressing(unom: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get().subscribe((data => {
              this.addressing = data;
         }); 
    }
```

Another ways to create observable and fill it inside service.

Comment: Its upto the programmer, no hard n fast rule

Comment: A service should provide methods to acquire data, not store them.

Comment: In respective components variable i.e. in-memory ideally. If you want to persist them, use localStorage.

Comment: How I tend to do things in Angular is have the service only get the data, then have the component (or another service) process the data. My services are mainly one-liners that just do a `return this.http.get<Type>("url");`, then my components subscribe to that to get the information

Comment: I think component should not store data, only use and render. So any manipulations must be in server where I loda data. Also assign data to service varaible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the data inmemory, I would use [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/) or [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/). You will be able to fetch the data once and use it in multiple components, as long as you don't refresh the page.

If you want to keep the data after you reload the page, id use local- or sessionstorage.